# format error while uploading data from text table in to hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

**i am able to upload the data but the problem is with null values where is   the issue ,is there some format issue ?**

**create table in local table using***

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee21( eid string, name String,
      salary String, destination String)
       COMMENT 'Employee details'
       ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\073'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
       STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**loading table in to hive**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/sma/mit123/s12.txt' INTO TABLE employee21;

     hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/mh/m123/s12.txt' INTO TABLE employee21;
     Copying data from file:/home/mh/mh123/s12.txt
     Copying file: file:/home/mh/mh123/s12.txt
     Loading data to table default.employee21
      Table default.employee21 stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 1, num_rows:     0, total_size: 156, raw_data_size: 0]
    OK
    Time taken: 0.702 seconds
        hive> show tables;
         OK
       employee1
       employee11
       employee21
  Time taken: 0.159 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

 **checking the table data in hive**

         hive> select * from employee21;
        OK
        1231  mh          45000    Proof reader NULL    NULL    NULL
        1203  Masthanvali 40000    Technical writer NULL    NULL    NULL
        1204  Kiran       40000    Hr Admin NULL    NULL    NULL
        1205  Kranthi     30000    Op Admin NULL    NULL    NULL
       Time taken: 0.104 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: it seems that your fields are not delimited by '\073`

Comment: its mentioned in line no 5

Comment: I meant in the actual text file that you are loading.. what are the delimiters?

Comment: text file with spaces between the columns

Comment: But you also have spaces in the destination column